# Filtring a vector with loop for by step of 3 matlab code

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I had a vector that I wanted to filter by keeping only the elements with the value 1, but using the `for loop` with `step 3` , and It is compulsory to filter the elements 3 by 3. I try with this code

```
T=[1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 ]';
    k=1:3:length(T);
    for i=1:3:length(T)
    S(S(i:i+3)==1);
    end
```

But I get this error message `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`
Any help please to solve that.

Comment: What's your desired result? `S=[1 1 1 1]`?

Comment: I want to have this in result S=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1] but using the for loop with step 3

Comment: So you want all the 1's, what the meaning of step 3 here?

Comment: Is `S` defined earlier in your code? If not, you're getting the error because there is no data in `S(i:i+3)`, since S is empty... It would help massively for you to give a desired output with your example input, and state what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to describe what/why you want this better. The solution to your code else is just `S=T(T==1)`

Comment: What I mean is that I try to filter the first 3 elements and keep those with the value 1, then move to 3 that follows and keep those with the value 1 and so on until the last 3 elements

Comment: Filter as in Kalman filter? OR high band frequency filter? **define** filter. What is the difference from what you describe to "keep all 1s"?

Comment: @Wolfie : Good remark I try this but still not gives me what I want `for i=1:3:(length(T)-3)
   S=T(T(i:i+3)==1);
end`

Comment: @Ander Biguri In reality, I have hundreds of data on a vector that I try to filter block by block with certain conditions, and what I present here is just a very simple example to know how to use the for loop with step

Comment: However, you still have not explained what "filter" means. Unless you take your time to explain us what you are triying to do, we are not going to be able to help

Comment: I mean here by filter just select or keep, it's just an expression and not a real filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- You want to step through your data in blocks of 3
- Within each block, you have some test condition and want to keep the data which meets it, here you are using a simplified example of `== 1`.
- The output should be a vector of all data which meets the condition.

Adapting your code:

```
% Initial Data
T=[1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 ]';
% Vector to be populated with filtered data
S = [];
% Step through in blocks of 3, note there is no check for whether
% all elements of T are covered, as size(T,1) may not be divisible by 3.
for ii = 1:3:size(T,1)-2
    % Test condition of T(ii:ii+2) == 1
    % Note it should be ii+2 not ii+3, as ii:ii+2 is the elements ii, ii+1, ii+2. 
    % If you used ii:ii+3, that would be FOUR elements!
    %
    % S grows every loop, appending the values of T in this block of 3 which meet the condition
    Tblock = T(ii:ii+2);
    S = [S; Tblock(Tblock==1)];
end
```

A better way to do this would be to not loop in blocks of 3, but to simply do

```
 S = T(T == 1);
```

However, you suggest in the comments and question that the blocks of 3 are important, as the actual process is much more complicated.

Comment: If you want to preserve the blocks of 3, you can reshape T to be [3xn] and then make a condition on the new matrix, no need of loops.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is really what I seek to do by this simple example, but it gives again this error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` And I think it is logical when it holds ii = size (T, 1) and when increases by 2 in the loop (ii+2)

Comment: You right. But it also says that length of T does not divide by 3... So how would you want to deal with that?

Comment: @PhDMa, `ii = 1:3:size(T,1)` will not exceed `size(T,1)`. You can see from `1:3:9 = [1,4,7]`, not `[1,4,7,10]`. This code should run without an indexing error, try using `clear` at the start of your code, you may have some workspace clutter.

Comment: @PhDMa, in Matlab, in the Editor tab, click the Breakpoints drop down and select "Stop On Errors". Then you can see what the value of `ii` is when it errors. Alternatively set a breakpoint on line 1 and step through the code line by line using `F10`. Alternatively, try restarting Matlab and copying that code into a new script, I can't see any reason those 5 lines could cause an error.

Comment: I just applied what you told me, the error is when ii = 13 (last iteration), but there is also another problem is that in result S = [1; 1; 0; 0; 1; 0] as you see this still contains the values 0

Comment: @PhDMa, I've edited my code, it now works as expected.